# How to pass data in react-hook-form with hidden input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit, react-hook-form

LANGUAGE : javascript (with react, redux toolkit, react hook form)

CONTEXT : So i have an application with a form.
The user need to check a job and a graduate Level to see what salary he can pretend

here are the input for job and graduate

```
 <input {...register('job')}
            type="radio"
            value="Web developer"
          />
 <input {...register('graduate')}
            type="radio"
            value="2"
          />
```

I'm getting the salary with a useEffect.
Every time the graduate or the job change, i dispatch "getSalaryAmount".

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (graduate && job ) {
      dispatch(getSalaryAmount(graduate , job ));
    } else { 
    }
  }, [job , graduate , dispatch]);
```

here is my getSalaryAmount, i dispatch the answer with redux toolkit :

```
export const getSalaryAmount = (graduate , job ) => async (dispatch) => {
  await axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}salary/${graduate }/${job}`,
  }).then((res) => {
    dispatch(getSalary(res.data.salaryAmount));
  });
};
```

Then in my form, i've got an input hidden with the salary value.

```
  const salaryAmount = useSelector((state) => state.salaryAmount );

 <> <input hidden {...register('salary')} />  {salaryAmount } </>
```

Here is my problem :

- I need to pass a "value" to my hidden input, but how to do that if the salaryAmount is a dynamic value ?

I've already try to pass a "value" in the hidden input but it keep the first get value and after don't change

ps : i need to pass it because after a submit, i made a post request with axios to send the form data.

Thank you